# Change the custom post type names (for translation)

Tags: php, wordpress, url, custom-post-type

I want to change "service" and "testimonial" url heap in the Wordpress. Because my domain is in Turkish language and my page is in Turkish too, like this: "http://www.sitename.com/service/sirketler-hukuku/". But "service" and "testimonial" words are in English as you know. So it looks like pulled tooth.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any plugin for both? or anything else?

Comment: I don't use any plugin. Actually, I did not find any plugin. If I find any plugin for changing service and testimonial heap, I want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some part of your code the function `register_post_type()` will get called, one each for testimonial and services.

You need to change the parameters of this function, specifically the 'rewrite' parameter. If you wrote these functions in your own code, changing is easy. If not hopefully the theme or plugin has filters you can change the parameters from.

So something like

```
register_post_type( /*other parameters*/, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'turkish for testimonial') );
```

Read more at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best solution for me.